# Javascript "close button" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Today I tried to make the simpliest close button in javaScript. It unfortunately does not work. This is how it look like:

```
<div id="popup_bg">
<div id="popup_window">
<span id="popup_close">
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

and the js code is:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
        $("#popup_close").click(function() {
        $("#popup_bg").fadeOut();
        event.stopPropagation();
        });
</script>
```

I'd also like to make it apply to any of those "popups", so I'd probably change my it to something like $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(); - is it possible to do so?

Thanks for help guys! :)

@EDIT

As none of Your solutions work I'll place my code literally :D Maybe You'll find some mistakes that makes it faulty:

```
<?php if(isset(errors['user'])) : ?>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $("#popup_close").on('click', function() {
        $("#popup_background").fadeOut();
        //event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="popup_background" >
    <div class="popup_window">
        <span class="title">
        error
        </span>
        <span class="message"><?php echo errors['user']; ?>
        </span>
        <span id="popup_close" class="button">OK</span>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope that will help You spot any errors. It displays correctly, I click on my "OK" span, nothing happens :p I hate js :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code, the jquery part of the code is working..
Check here: Jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Zahinize/7YD4D/13/

You should rewrite your conditional **If** statement like this,

```
 <? ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function()
  {
    $("#popup_close").on('click', function() {
    $("#popup_background").fadeOut();
    //event.stopPropagation();
    });
   });
  </script>

 <div id="popup_background" >
  <div class="popup_window">
    <span class="title">
    error
    </span>
    <span class="message">

    <?php 
     if(isset(errors['user'])){      
      echo errors['user']; 
      }
    ?>
     </span>
    <span id="popup_close" class="button">OK</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

set error_reporting at that the top..

See more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Maybe this would help, but frankly i haven't seen error handling like this:    **error['user']** anywhere.. you should see error handling for writing better code ;)

Comment: oh, I know, but it's not really "error handling" ;p basically it's what's send via $_POST ;d

the problem is this "popup" should never appear unless this "error" is set - that's the reason for setting it up that high.

Comment: and what I did - I deleted all conditionals and it still does not work... :|

I did the check and it does not go inside the function after clicking the "button".

Comment: Alright, I made it work now :) I put php if to set additional class "hidden" to my element if this variable is not set. That way it won't appear unless this variable contains something.

Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, you can also wrap this code inside a function myfunction(){ -- Your html, php code  -- },  then simply check      if(isset(errors['user'])){ myfunction(); } for better encapsulation..

Answer (score 1):

IDs must unique, you should use classes instead:

```
<div class="popup_bg">
   <div class="popup_window">
      <span class="popup_close"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then for selecting the target parent of the clicked element you can use `closest` method:

```
$(function() { 
    $(".popup_close").click(function(event) {
       $(this).closest(".popup_bg").fadeOut();
       // event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Note that in your code `event` is `undefined` you should pass the event object to your handler.

Comment: I have my IDs unique, I did write it badly tho :P - I have different popups on different sites ;) they are also put in conditional statement, not appearing at the same time (not parsed either).

Comment: @user1515145 Okay, I meant if you have multiple elements with the same IDs jQuery only selects the first element with that specific ID, regrading your question, you can use `closest` method instead of several `parent`s.

Comment: Still not working, I added my code to the original question, maybe there is a stupid mistake I can't see.

Answer (score 1):

Add `document.ready` and/or use `.on` function

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    $(function(){
        $("#popup_close").on('click', function() {
            $("#popup_bg").fadeOut();
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, ID's may not repeat in your document, use other selector like class

Comment: I have my IDs unique, I did write it badly tho :P - I have different popups on different sites ;) they are also put in conditional statement, not appearing at the same time (not parsed either).

Comment: @Jai you are right.. I forgot to add the event name (`click`)

Comment: @udidu Still problem persists `event.stopPropagation()` in your code is useless, that can't do anything.

Comment: Still not working, I added my code to the original question, maybe there is a stupid mistake I can't see.

Comment: @user1515145 see the ” at this line `<script type=”text/javascript”>`, try changing them to a regular "

Comment: @udidu I did it, nothing has changed : /

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one popup better to use class instead of id.

**Example.**

```
$(function()
{
    $(".popup_close").on('click',(function()
    {
        $(this).parents("div.popup_bg").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

And **html**

```
<div class = "popup_bg">
    <div class = "popup_window">
        <span class = "popup_close"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have my IDs unique, I did write it badly tho :P - I have different popups on different sites ;) they are also put in conditional statement, not appearing at the same time (not parsed either).

Answer (score 0):

You need some content in your span or set height and with. Then you will be able to click on it and it will work.
Avoid tricks with `parent().parent()` this may break if you change your div structure.
As others have said use the jquery document ready (read a tutorial) and use classes not ids if you intend to reuse the code (read a CSS tutorial)...

Comment: Yup, but my div struct is static - it's always the same :) and it has content, I just showed the structure here ;)

Comment: I understand but maybe some day you will change it or someone else will and then your script will break if you forget about the parent selectors. I call that fragile code.

Comment: I'll have that in mind and use classes (I was meant to do it after I make it work).